# Hide parent node after click on child

Tags: d3.js, parent-child, force-layout

I am using this demo http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1062288 and implemented it successfully but I want to hide the parent node after I click on it and child comes as well as on clicking the child node if it has a subchild the child node should disappear. I mean hiding the child node because it consider as a parent node of sub child.

A jsfiddle

Here after I click on animate flare should disappear and again on click of animate flare will have to come.

Comment: Can you please describe more clearly what you want to happen with your 'parent' node when you click it? For instance, do you want one child node to replace it? This matters especially because you could have more than one child for each parent node.

Comment: When I click on parent node 'animate' as in jsfiddle 'flare' and all other except 'animate' should disappear / hide and child nodes of 'animate' will come. I think this is some how tough because the main node must not hide or disappear. So if possible show me the way how can I show only clicked node and it's child other connected nodes to the root should disappear.